# How can I get the first string out of a list in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this string:

```
   foreach (string error in result.Errors)
```

When I check it says that result.Errors is IEnumerable

I tried to get the first of these like this but it does not work:

```
   var error1 = result.Errors[0];
```

Can someone give me advice on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: access the `error` variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the first element from an IEnumerable<T> in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497261/how-do-i-get-the-first-element-from-an-ienumerablet-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly duplicate of [How do I get the first element from an IEnumerable<T> in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497261/how-do-i-get-the-first-element-from-an-ienumerablet-in-net)

Before all that check for null:

```
if(result.Errors == null) 
   return null;
```

Try to use [linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 result.Errors.First() ?
```

if you are not sure if there're any errors: use

```
result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()
```

it will return null if collection is empty

And one more [option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
result.Errors.ElementAt(0)
```

or hard code:

```
new List<string>(result.Errors)[0] // but it's not pretty at aall
//or as poined bellow via extensions
result.Errors.ToList()[0]
result.Errors.ToArray()[0]
```

Comment: Why not use `ToList()` instead of `new List()` ?

Comment: it's just sintax sugare via extensions, isn't it? but yes, it's easier to use

Comment: `ToList()[0]` will throw exception if list is empty

Comment: @Fabio it will exception if  it's null

Comment: @Artiom, if `.ToList()` return empty list, then trying to access item in index 0 will throw `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: @Fabio now I got your point. You are right. But I believe this scenario smells of bad architecture: the code shouldn't be even executed if no errors.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
  String error1 = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
```

if there's a possibility that `result` itself can be `null`, than you have to add an additinal check:

```
  String error1 = result == null ? null : result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
```

in all the cases, if `error1 == null`, there're *no errors*, otherwise, `error1` is the *first one*.

Comment: @Fabjan: Thank you, I've edited the answer (trenary operator to check `result == null` case)

Comment: What if `Errors` is null? In the question was nothing about checking for nulls. Only how to get first item of collection. @Dmitriy you question was right before editing

Comment: @Fabio This answer is the only answer here that will not throw if `result` or `.Errors` is `null`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var error1 = result.Errors.First().ToString();
```

OR

```
var error1 = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LINQ` extension method `FirstOrDefault()`
which return `null`(in case of `String`) if collection is empty

```
string first = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
```

`.First()` will throw exception if colleciton is empty

Comment: If `result.Errors` is `null` then `FirstOrDefault` method in your answer will throw `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @Fabjan, if `result` is null and exception will be thrown, then this is will be another question

Answer (score 2):

Try This.If string is `NULL`  empty will be returned.

```
var error1 = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault() != null ? result.Errors.FirstOrDefault():string.Empty;
```

OR

```
 var error1 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()) ? result.Errors.FirstOrDefault():string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `First()`

```
result.Errors.First();
```

or if `result.Errors` doesn't contain anything use `FirstOrDefault`

```
result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
```